# Action button not displaying in vuetify v-data-table

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify-datatable

everything in the code works fine i mean data is properly fetching from database but the only prlb is the edit and delete icons are not displaying

```
<template>
  <div class="d-flex flex-column pa-5">
    <div class="d-flex pb-5">
      <h2 class="mr-auto">Category List</h2>
      <NuxtLink to="/admin/cform">
        <v-btn variant="tonal" color="primary"> +Add Category </v-btn>
      </NuxtLink>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-center">
      <v-data-table
        v-model:items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
        :headers="headers"
        :items="categories"
        class="data-table rounded-lg"
        hover
      >
      <template #item.category="{ item }">
          <strong>{{ item.category }}</strong>
        </template> 

        <template v-slot:item.actions="{item}">
           <v-btn 
            color="primary"
            class="elevation-0"
            icon
            variant="plain"
            @click="editCategory(item)"
           ><v-icon> mdi-pencil-outline</v-icon>
           </v-btn>
           <v-btn
                color="error"
                variant="plain"
                class="elevation-0"
                icon
                @click="deleteCategory(item)"
                ><v-icon>mdi-trash-can-outline</v-icon
              ></v-btn>

      </template>
      </v-data-table>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Can someone tell me what m i missing or doing wrong  in here because then i have to add proper functionality to it

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      itemsPerPage: 5,
        categories: [],
        //actions:"",

        headers: [
         { title: "Category ID", value: "CategoryId" },
        { title: "Category", value: "Category" },
        { title: "Actions", value: "Actions", sortable: false },
      ],
    };
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says you are using Vue 3 in the tags, which means you are using Vuetify 3. In the current version of VDataTable, use `key` instead of `value` in the header declaration:

```
headers: [
  { title: "Category ID", key: "CategoryId" },
  { title: "Category", key: "Category" },
  { title: "Actions", key: "Actions", sortable: false },
],
```

---

Also, the `#item.<column name>` slot name has to match the `key`, which would make it `#item.Category` (upper-cased "category"), not `#item.category`. And the `item` in the slot props is the internal table item, not the entry from the array you passed in. But it can be accessed through the `raw` property. So the slot should be:

```html
<template #item.Category="{ item }">
  <strong>{{ item.raw.category }}</strong>
</template>
```

---

With these changes, your table renders in the [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)